# Clickable href with the attachments

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, attachments, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a list with the following columns:

- Job Description (Single Line of Text)
- Attachments

And also I got a Column named "internLink" which contains the exact name of the document which is attached.

Now I wanted to ask, if it is possible to just get the document name of the attachment with JSON and insert it into a JSON href?

Comment: I assume the "internalLink" column stores the document name. And you goal is to use the name to create a link which users can click and redirects to the document, correct? Where do you want to display the link? Are you using SharePoint Online modern list with json formatting?

Comment: Yes exactly

We are using Sahrepoint Online modern yes

Comment: You want to get the document name from "internLink" field or SharePoint default Attachments field?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the attachments field is not directly accessible in List Formatting. However, if you have the filename stored in the `internLink` column then you should be able to build a format to link to the attachment. Assuming you apply this to the `internLink` column below (if another column the `internLink` field still needs to be in the view and you'll switch out `@currentField` with `[$internLink]`):

```
{
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "href": "=@currentWeb + '/Lists/YourListNameHere/Attachments/' + [$ID] + '/' + @currentField + '?web=1'"
    }
}
```