# Conditional formatting if list item has attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I customized a list form via JSON to sort the entries for the user.
Now I want to modify a text in the header based on if there's an attachment in that list item or not.

I already included the attachment-column in my list. My code (not working) so far is:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$Attachments] == 0, 'no attachment', 'item has attachment')"
```

I also tried to put the number in '', changed it to true and false. Nothing works.

Comment: Are you trying to add this JSON in list view or list form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior of JSON list formatting in SharePoint. Unfortunately, the "Attachments" field is not directly accessible in JSON list formatting.

**Similar thread**: [Clickable href with the attachments](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287575/clickable-href-with-the-attachments)

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

**Update**:

Attachments column is now supported in JSON formatting. Check documentation: [Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

You can use the expression like this:

```
"txtContent": "=if([$Attachments] == '0', 'no attachment', 'item has attachment')"
```